# Replacing jQuery and HTML at runtime

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my *HTML* and *jQuery* snippet:

```
<div id="navigator">    
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <a href="#">Competitors</a>
    </div>
    <div class="video-browser">
        <div class="folder">
            <a id="221" class="accessor">
                <img src="/assets/images/folder.png" />
                <span>Aron#1</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("a.accessor").click(function(event) {
            var cId = this.id;
            $.get("/video/" + cId)
            .done(function(data){
                $("#navigator").html(data);
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                alert("An error occured during request. Please try again later!");
            });
        });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when the response comes, the jquery replaces the *HTML* content, but it also replaces itself with some other script (this is what comes from *jQuery* request as response). So firstly I get this in the view page. The problem is that when I'm looking in the *HTML* source, the *HTML* and the script is unchanged. So you understand that when I click further, I get some weird behavior.

Can anyone tell me if what I'm doing is good, and if yes, what can be the problem with my script?

Thanks.

---

EDIT1:

The response that replaces the current *HTML* content is:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="/video">Competitors</a>
    <span>&gt;</span>
    <a href="#">Aron#1</a>
</div>
<div class="video-browser">
    <div class="folder">
        <a id="261_241" class="accessor">
            <img src="/assets/images/movie_file.png" />
            <span>test</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.accessor").click(function(event) {
        var compId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("_"));
        var movieId = this.id.substring(this.id.indexOf("_") + 1);
        $.get("/video/" + compId + "/" + movieId)
            .done(function(data){
                $("#videoPlayerDiv").html(data).html();
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                alert("An error occured during request. Please try again later!");
            });
        });
     </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need inline JS?

Comment: Have you tried $("#navigator").html($(data).html()); ?

Comment: @BrianWigginton it would be much simpler for me in that way. And even more clear in my scenario.

Comment: Could you move the click handler outside of #navigator? What about adding a script tag just before the closing body tag with your handler?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the data coming from `$.get("/video/" + cId)` call? Depending on that, there may be a way around your problem.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Yes. It does not work.

Comment: @BrianWigginton I moved it in the header, but it still doesn't work. What is interesting is that when I access my application that is deployed on my machine, it works well. This issue occures when I have the application deployed on a different machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after a lot of struggling I finally realized that it's a problem of deployment. The *jQuery* behaves well, but it can't do some things due to security restrictions that my application has. It is related to the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the others have suggested, I would suggest moving your script out of the html. So initially you could have something like this:

```
<div id="navigator">    
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <a href="#">Competitors</a>
    </div>
    <div class="video-browser">
        <div class="folder">
            <a id="221" class="accessor">
                <img src="/assets/images/folder.png" />
                <span>Aron#1</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the script out side **with an id tag**, but see if in your response data, you can send the HTML part and the JS part seperately. Then you can do what I've shown below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" id="replacableJS">
    $("a.accessor").click(function(event) {
        var cId = this.id;
        $.get("/video/" + cId)
        .done(function(data){
            $("#navigator").html(data.htmlPart); // NOTE:
            $("#replacableJS").text(data.jsPart); // NOTE:
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            alert("An error occured during request. Please try again later!");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: the real problem is that if I write `alert($("#navigator").html());` after I change the content, It prints out the replaced text, but in the source is the old one.

Comment: @artaxerxe As someone mentioned earlier here, the source may show the 'old' one depending on how your looking at it and which browser/tool you are using on the client side to look at the source. However, is the old source causing a problem? I mean, if `alert($("#navigator").html());` is showing you the replaced text, then I'm not sure I follow where you are still having an issue.... Could you clarify that..?

Comment: Ok. The source is showing as expected (watched with Chrome developer tools). But the behavior is still not as expected.

Comment: @artaxerxe Do you mean that the newly received script part is not behaving as it should?

Comment: I put the scripts in the header, and that should be fine. But the problem is that sometimes it changes the *HTML* content, sometimes not.